# Add css style to elements of 2 lists on element click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 lists of elements. When I click on an element of first list (it is a link), I basically need to add css class 'is-active' to that element AND to corresponding item from another list. I think they have to be in separate lists, as they are in two different bootstrap columns for mobile friendliness. I am currently styling elements from first list with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs li').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('is-active');
        $('.tabs li').not(this).removeClass('is-active');
    });
})
```

Can't select elements from the other list though.. Any ideas how can I achieve this functionality with css, js/jquery?

My html structure currently is like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tabs-title is-active">
            <a href="#">title_1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-title">
            <a href="#">title_2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="tabs-content">
        <div class="tabs-panel is-active">
            <div class="entry">
                <p>content_1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-panel">
            <div class="entry">
                <p>content_2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on 2nd link from first column, the 2nd div from second column should get 'is-active' class. Is this possible?

I guess lists do not have corresponding elements right now. What do I need to have the items linked in some way?

Comment: Could you provide us with the HTML code of the lists? That would make the trouble shooting a little easier.

Comment: How are they corresponding links? Via data-attribute, href, or sort order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example, since we don't know what your list looks like.

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="letters">
  <li>item a</li>
  <li>item b</li>
  <li>item c</li>
</ul>
```

Also, it's easier to remove all instances of the `is-active` class and then add it just to the target elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tabs li').click(function(){
    var index = $('.tabs li').index(this);

    $('.tabs li, .letters li').removeClass('is-active');

    $(this).addClass('is-active');
    $('.letters li').each(function(i) {
        if (i == index)
        $(this).addClass('is-active');
    })
  });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fzeauw7a/

Comment: That seems nice. Wasn't aware of index function. Will try this!

Comment: Please +1 if you like the solution :)